# Should it be, rather than God or Nature, Nature in God?

Tags: theology, spinoza

Spinoza's theology is sometimes represented by the phrase 'God or Nature'. However, he specifically notes that only two attributes, out of an infinity of attributes of God, are cognizable to us - mind and extension; extension being that of Nature in its outward sense, and mind, being Nature in its inward sense - human nature.

But doesn't this description show that Nature is *in* God, rather than Nature *is* God?

Comment: this site isn't for doing philosophy m8

Comment: @user3293056: I think you right; what do you propose when I have a philosophical gene? I could try writing a thesis I suppose, or a book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really grasping where the question you is.

You state that for Spinoza, we can know either God's infinity or God's attributes. Spinoza calls what is grasped under the former "God" and under the latter "nature". It's not so much that nature is God or God is nature, but that the terms nature and God refer to the same thing comprehended differently...

Comment: Ok, what I was actually after was what 'Nature or God' meant; I was probably asking the question too rhetorically...

Comment: Except that what is Nature, is the two attributes cognisable by us - mind & extension - of an infinite number of attributes; or one could say only a small part of what is Nature is cognisable by us; so 'nature' in Nature.

Comment: To be certain that the term God is not misconstrued as having any 'anthropomorphic' status and to offer a 'complete' definition of 'god' Spinoza, in fact, employs a trilogy; God/Nature/Substance. They are synonymous and interchangeable. Taken together they reflect the 'immanence''  of the 'divinity'. Everything imaginable is both 'in god' and simultaneously 'is god'. Very difficult to comprehend, but doable with deep reflection over time @Mozibur Ullah. Cheers, CS